# Set user avatar from front end in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, avatar-generation

I am working on user registration page. When user upload the image then I attached that image in user meta by `attachment id`, now when user add the comment then his uploaded photo is not appearing in comment list beside his comment. After some search I got some information in avatar...but cant get any idea about how to upload avatar from front side?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if ( function_exists( 'get_avatar' ) ) {
  echo get_avatar( $user->user_email, 50);
 } else {
  //alternate gravatar code for < 2.5
  $grav_url = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar.php?gravatar_id=
     " . md5($user->user_email) . "&default=" . urlencode($default) . "&size=" .   $size;
  echo "<img src='$grav_url' height='50px' width='50px' />";
}
?>
```

Please check with this code. This should work.

Comment: thx for your response but i am confused in varialbe that you write in function...means what is $comment in get_avatar?

Comment: is there any plugins so that i can set user avatar by givin user profile picture id(attachement id)?

Comment: <?php echo get_avatar( $user->user_email, 50 ); ?> must echo it.